# CakePHP - populating select form

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to populate a drop down select form with values from a database.

Here is what I have currently.

```
$modes = Set::combine($this->Setting->find('all', array('conditions' => array('setting_name LIKE' => 'mode_%'))), '{n}.Setting.id','{n}.Setting.setting_name');
$this->set('modes', $modes);
```

Then in the view, this is what I have

```
echo $form->select('current_mode',$modes);
```

That output

```
<select name="data[Setting][current_mode]" id="SettingCategoryId">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="2">mode_2</option>
<option value="1">mode_1</option>
<option value="3">mode_3</option>
</select>
```

The output that I have right now almost work but how can I make the output to be like this?

```
<select name="data[Setting][current_mode]" id="SettingCategoryId">
<option value="mode_2">Title 2</option>
<option value="mode_1">Title 1</option>
<option value="mode_3">Title 3</option>
</select>
```

Note:
1. no default option with empty value
2. Option's value isn't the id and titles comes from a "title" field in the table

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See http://book.cakephp.org/view/1022/find-list and http://book.cakephp.org/view/1062/displayField.

```
$settings = $this->Setting->find('list', array(
    'conditions' => array('Setting.setting_name LIKE' => 'mode_%'),
    'fields'     => array('Setting.id', 'Setting.title')
));
$this->set(compact('settings'));

// view
echo $this->Form->input('current_mode', array(
    'type'    => 'select',
    'options' => $settings,
    'empty'   => false
));
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to loop through modes and create an option for each mode, like so:

```
$options = array();

foreach($modes as $mode)
{
    $options[$mode] = "Title " . $mode;
}

echo $form->select('current_mode', $options);
```

You can either put the above logic in your view, or you can do it in your controller, and then set the variable like this:

```
$this->set("options", $options);
```

The docs here explain the select element method pretty well:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1430/select

Comment: Vote down without any explanation? It's not as concise as deceze's solution, but this answer isn't wrong, nor is it any less performant.