# my Select list shows the ID's not the values,CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

How can i get categories names to the select list not their ID's !! , I'm using CakePHP

the 'categories' table has only two columns (id, name)

the view part :

```
echo $this->Form->input('category',array(
                                             'type' => 'select', 
                                             'options' => $categories,   
                                             'empty' => 'select category'        
                                        ));
```

the association :

```
class Job extends AppModel{
public $name = 'Job';
public $belongsTo = array('Category');
}
```

and the controller :

```
$categories= $this->Job->Category->find('list');
$this->set('categories',$categories);
```

the result is a select list with 1,2,3,4,5,6 values

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5659501/689579 possible help

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP - populating select form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659384/cakephp-populating-select-form)

Answer (score 1):

You needs to edit your controller code as following :

```
$categories= $this->Job->Category->find('list',array('fields'=>array('Category.id','Category.name')));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use virtual field in cakephp.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html

also Line main in ctp file

`foreach($times as $key => $value ){ $timesList[$value] = $value; } $times = $timesList`

use as per your model-controller. for mor info. plz follow this link .here i face same problem and i got solution.

[virtual field are not working in cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26749934/virtual-field-are-not-working-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 0):

In cakephp 3.X

```
// Common Usage:
$users = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'mark'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'jane'],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'sally'],
    ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'jose'],
];
$results = Hash::extract($users, '{n}.id');
// $results equals:
// [1,2,3,4];
```

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/hash.html