# virtual field are not working in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

my controller .

```
$times=$this->Time->find('list',array('fields'=>$this->Time->virtualFields['name_price'] ));
$this->set('time',compact($times));
```

and i added below line in my model Time

```
public $virtualFields = array('name_price' => 'concat(Time.varaddress1, "-", Time.varaddress2)');
```

and my ctp file is below

```
<?echo $this->Form->input('intaddressid', array(
'options' => $time,'label'=>false,'empty' => '(Select  Information)'

 ,'class' => 'form-control border_none' 
));?>
```

but now in output i got nothing in select filed.!!

and when i echo $time i got `Array ( )

and i want in select field

```
<option>varaddress1,varaddress2</option>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your controller code like as :

```
$times=$this->Time->find('list',array('fields'=>array('Time.id','Time.name_price')));
$this->set(compact('times'));
```

Comment: k. thanks thats display both var1,var2 value  now i want to save that both value in db..! right now in database it store id. so what to do ? thanks :)

Comment: To save both values in database please change controller code as $times=$this->Time->find('list',array('fields'=>array('Time.name_price','Time.name_price')));

Comment: or in short. i want to print. that select hotel name in admin panel. right now it print id..thanks.

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Time.na‌​me_price' in 'field list'

Comment: Than please use $times=$this->Time->find('list',array('fields'=>array('Time.id','Time.name_price')));
foreach($times as $key => $value ){
    $timesList[$value] = $value;
}
$times = $timesList;